# Akka HTTP in Docker

Tags: java, docker, akka

I've an Akka HTTP service, built in Java, that creates an executable jar. Outside of the container, it runs alright. Inside the container, it starts fine. But I'm not able to access the service.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8

COPY target/my-service-api-1.0.0-allinone.jar /app.jar

EXPOSE 8181 8282 8383

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Build:

```
docker image build -t my-service-api:v1 .
```

Run:

```
docker run -p 8181:8181 -p 8282:8282 -p 8383:8383 --rm my-service-api:v1
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing? I've been searching around for a while with no success so far.

Comment: how do you run the docker? is it via docker toolbox or docker ce something2? is this happen on linux or windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your service to `0.0.0.0:container_port` (inside container), mount `container_port` to `host_port` and check that `host_port` open on host.